# How to display data from different data tables? One to many reationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

So, I have Model who has many uploaded Videos. Model and models_videos are different tables. I need to display video from each model based on their id.

ModelController:

```
 public function index() 
    {
        $models = NewModel::all();

        $model_video = NewModelVideos::all();

        return view('admin.model_new_videos.index')
        ->with('models', $models)
        ->with('model_video', $model_video);

    }
```

Models

```
 class NewModel extends Model
    {
 protected $table = 'models';

    protected $guarded  = ['id'];

    protected $sortable = ['id', 'name', 'about'];

    public function videos()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\NewModels\NewModelVideos','model_id' ,'id');
        }
    }


    class NewModelVideos extends Model
    {
        use Sortable;

        protected $table = 'models_videos';

        protected $guarded  = ['id'];

        protected $sortable = ['id', 'model_id', 'title', 'video'];

        public function model()
        {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\NewModels\NewModel', 'id');
        }   

    }
```

And View:

```
@foreach($model_video as $model)

    <h1>{{ $model->title }} </h1>
        {{ $model->video }}   

@endforeach
```

I can't get video which belongs to specific model. Sorry, I am new and still learning

Comment: Have you specified a `foreign` key when you made tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the column what is related to `NewModel`:

```
class NewModelVideos extends Model
    {
        use Sortable;

        protected $table = 'models_videos';

        protected $guarded  = ['id'];

        protected $sortable = ['id', 'model_id', 'title', 'video'];

        public function model()
        {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\NewModels\NewModel', 'id', 'model_id'); //<-- here
        }   

    }
```

If you did not specified a `foreign key` for the models: here is what docs says [One To One](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the id (or the custom $primaryKey) column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the user's id column in the user_id column of the Phone record. If you would like the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third argument to the hasOne method specifying your custom key:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

That is mean that you can do it this way too:

```
class NewModelVideos extends Model
    {
        use Sortable;

        protected $table = 'models_videos';

        protected $guarded  = ['id'];

        protected $sortable = ['id', 'model_id', 'title', 'video'];

        public function model()
        {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\NewModels\NewModel', 'id', 'model_id'); //<-- here
        }   

    }
```